# Manga/manhua/manhwa in which the main character is randomly placed into a boy that's the "demon prince"

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The main character (MC) is randomly placed into a boy that's the "demon prince". The castle is already under attack. There's a captured princess that he finds and he pretends to be another captured person and gets out alive. He then heads to this city and meets a companion in a potion shop or book shop. The monsters listen to him. The MC is of child age. The story is fully colored and if I remember, our MC is an author who gets put into one of his stories after death.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And was the boy originally from another world?

Comment: @LogicDictates I'm pretty sure it was full of color, and if I remember correctly, the MC was an author

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Demon King of the Royal Class](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/demon-king-of-the-royal-class)*. it is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/demon-king-of-the-royal-class/info).

> Upon dying, the author of "The Demon King is Dead" is given two choices: go to hell or **be reborn in his novel and survive till the end**. The problem? He's reborn as **Baalier Junior, a weak demon prince**, after his realm was conquered! To make things worse, his attempt to escape somehow gets him enrolled as a student of the Royal Class in Gradias Temple, a prestigious human school. In the midst of plotlines and political schemes, can this author keep his identity a secret and reach a happy ending?

The protagonist is a webnovel author and dies shortly after reading multiple extremely critical comments of his latest work. After dying, he reincarnates within that work as a minor son of the demon lord; the demon lord (and presumably all his children) are killed in the prologue of the actual work. As mentioned in the question, he reincarnates in the middle of the battle.

[image: System message telling him to escape]

His escape plan is to use a camouflage spell and disguise himself among the human prisoners...

[image: Escape plan]

...Except when he arrives, all of the prisoners have already been killed, gruesomely. The only survivor turns out to be a young blonde girl. When the human forces arrive, they refer to her as a princess.

[image: Princess]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag `Author Transmigrated to Own Creation` and filtering out Shoujo/Josei works.